# Android Layout Issues in Android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am very beginner  in android. I am trying to design a screen, in which I had selected the navigation drawer template when I created the project. So the basic things required are in place, like toolbar on the top and a drawer menu icon on the left. Now i want to place an imageview below the toolbar and a list view below the imageview. I am using the following xml for the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sliderTempImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/slider_image1" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But the image covers the toolbar and fit the entire screen, even I had given fixed height of 100dp. Once the image view had set properly, I need to add list view also below the imageview.

Comment: Add the ImageView in `app_bar_main`.

Comment: Hi, I tried the same and it worked. But I wondered why it didnt work with the code as I given above. As I am new to Android, if I could know the reason, it would be give better understanding.

Comment: Refer my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer in comment : Add the ImageView in `app_bar_main` layout.

Reason why your code didn't work :

As per DrawerLayout specification

- DrawerLayout acts as a top-level container for window content that allows for interactive "drawer" views to be pulled out from one or both vertical edges of the window.
- To use a DrawerLayout, **position your primary content view as the first child** with width and height of match_parent and no layout_gravity because the XML order implies **z-ordering** and the drawer must be on top of the content . Add drawers as child views after the main content view and set the layout_gravity appropriately. **Drawers commonly use match_parent for height with a fixed width**.

Note the statement *position your primary content view as the first child*. In your case you want to place an ImageView below the Toolbar which means you want to modify the primary content. And the primary content is located inside `app_bar_main` layout.

> But the image covers the toolbar and fit the entire screen, even I had given fixed height of 100dp

It is because *Drawers commonly use **match_parent for height** with a fixed width*.

Also remove the `RelativeLayout` from the main layout as it is useless. Make the DrawerLayout as the root layout.

References :

1. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html
2. https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Answer (score 1):

Give an id to the app bar include:

```
android:id="@+id/mToolbar"
```

And add this in your ImageView:

```
android:layout_below="@id/mToolbar"
```

Since you're using `RelativeLayout`, you can use the layout below, above and other attributes to position your views.

Hint: Avoid hardcoding your values. Use `match_parent` or `wrap_content` or use your dimens.xml file to declare your values.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will move the values to dimens.xml. I tried to give the property android:layout_below for imageview. But it was not listing.

Comment: Properties not showing up is a common AS problem. You could try rebuilding the project. Since your parent layout is a `RelativeLayout` it's bound to show up.

Comment: Here the `RelativeLayout` is useless. And `android:layout_below` is not available for `DrawerLayout` as it is defined under `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` nested class.

Answer (score 1):

Actually RelativeLayout have feature to arrange its child below/above/left/right/center/top/bottom one layout to other using below property

BELOW
ABOVE
LEFT_OF
RIGHT_OF
CENTER_IN_PARENT
ALIGN_PARENT_TOP
ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM